# Access JSCall Invoker via the bridge in React Native Module

Tags: react-native, react-native-jsi

I am trying to access the jsCallInvoker method which is a reference to the JS thread on the react native bridge, but in xcode i dont see the reference to the method, i have forked the react-native-mmkv library but havent got access to the above variable. I would want to know if i need to add any more header files, or is there any other way i can get access to the JSinvoker method

I am using React version 0.66 with hermes enabled

```
#import "MmkvModule.h"
#import "JSIUtils.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge+Private.h>
#import <ReactCommon/CallInvoker.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <jsi/jsi.h>
#import <MMKV/MMKV.h>
#import "MmkvHostObject.h"

using namespace facebook;

@implementation MmkvModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(MMKV)

+ (NSString*)getPropertyAsStringOrNilFromObject:(jsi::Object&)object
                                   propertyName:(std::string)propertyName
                                        runtime:(jsi::Runtime&)runtime
{
    jsi::Value value = object.getProperty(runtime, propertyName.c_str());
    std::string string = value.isString() ? value.asString(runtime).utf8(runtime) : "";
    return string.length() > 0 ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:string.c_str()] : nil;
}

RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(install:(nullable NSString*)storageDirectory)
{
    NSLog(@"Installing global.mmkvCreateNewInstance...");
    //RCTBridge
    RCTBridge* bridge = [RCTBridge currentBridge]; /// THIS VARIABLE doesnt have access to js call invoker
    
    RCTCxxBridge* cxxBridge = (RCTCxxBridge*)bridge;
    if (cxxBridge == nil) {
        return @false;
    }
    
    using namespace facebook;
    
    auto jsiRuntime = (jsi::Runtime*) cxxBridge.runtime;
    if (jsiRuntime == nil) {
        return @false;
    }
    auto& runtime = *jsiRuntime;
    RCTUnsafeExecuteOnMainQueueSync(^{
      [MMKV initializeMMKV:storageDirectory];
    });
    
    // MMKV.createNewInstance()
    auto mmkvCreateNewInstance = jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(runtime,
                                                                       jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(runtime, "mmkvCreateNewInstance"),
                                                                       1,
                                                                       [](jsi::Runtime& runtime,
                                                                          const jsi::Value& thisValue,
                                                                          const jsi::Value* arguments,
                                                                          size_t count) -> jsi::Value {
        if (count != 1) {
            throw jsi::JSError(runtime, "MMKV.createNewInstance(..) expects one argument (object)!");
        }
        jsi::Object config = arguments[0].asObject(runtime);
        
        NSString* instanceId = [MmkvModule getPropertyAsStringOrNilFromObject:config propertyName:"id" runtime:runtime];
        NSString* path = [MmkvModule getPropertyAsStringOrNilFromObject:config propertyName:"path" runtime:runtime];
        NSString* encryptionKey = [MmkvModule getPropertyAsStringOrNilFromObject:config propertyName:"encryptionKey" runtime:runtime];
        
        auto instance = std::make_shared<MmkvHostObject>(instanceId, path, encryptionKey);
        return jsi::Object::createFromHostObject(runtime, instance);
    });
    runtime.global().setProperty(runtime, "mmkvCreateNewInstance", std::move(mmkvCreateNewInstance));
    
    NSLog(@"Installed global.mmkvCreateNewInstance!");
    return @true;
}

@end
```

[image: Xcode]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import

```
#import <React/RCTBridge+Private.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <ReactCommon/RCTTurboModule.h>
#import <jsi/jsi.h>
```

Also Your Podspec file needs to have the following dependencies

```
  s.dependency "React-Core"
  s.dependency "React"
  s.dependency "React-callinvoker"
```

Then do `pod install`